# Group bits in c

Tags: c

This is a question about c. I already create a mask which is 0xF, but I can's group the digit. Is there anything wrong with my for loop?

```
void print_hex(void *p)
{
  // copy the value that p points to into an unsigned integer variable.
  unsigned int x = *((unsigned int *) p);

  // In a loop, select four bits at a time using a mask.
  for(int i=0;i<32;i+=4){
    int y = (x >> i)&FOUR_BIT_BASK;
    printf("%d",x);
  }
```

Comment: What is `FOUR_BIT_BASK` defined as? Do you mean "mask?" Why not just use `0xF` or `(1 << 4) - 1`?

Comment: Hint: You're *badly* mangling `x` each time through this loop. Use a different variable for that slice.

Comment: Figured as much, but when using constants like that it helps to have that expressed in code as well so it's clear.

Comment: you mean create a new variable such as int y?

Comment: Either create a *different* variable so you don't mangle `x`, name doesn't really matter so long as it's different, or just supply that computation expression to `printf` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a typo. The code is printing the value of `x`, but intends to print `y`.

Instead of this:

```
printf("%d",x);
```

This:

```
printf("%d",y);
```

Also, without a space or newline in between print statements, those printed numbers are going to look jumbled together.  So maybe this:

```
printf("%d ",y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The printf function **was indeed using x** whereas it seems like the ***intention was to use the variable y***.

but on the other note, your printf function assumes size of int to be 32 but on a 64-bit machine where the processor word size is 64-bits and native int is of the size of processor word(essentially 64-bits) you might miss half of the data. As for good coding practice use **sizeof(int)** when performing such operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hex(void *p){
  // copy the value that p points to into an unsigned integer variable.
  unsigned int x = *((unsigned int *) p);

  const int bits = 8;
  const int nibble = bits/2;
  const int mask = 0xF; //expands to size of int
  // In a loop, select four bits at a time using a mask.
  printf("0x%x", y);
  for(int i=sizeof(int)*bits-nibble; i>=0; i-=nibble){
    int y = (x >> i) & mask;
    printf("%x", y);
  }
}

int x = 511;

void main(){
  print_hex(&x);
}
```

Output:

```
0x000001ff
```

**Note:** your code prints the bytes in little-endian whereas this code prints it in big endian (also note the %x format specifier in printf, which is used for printing hex values).